# angular js getting error using $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-injector

My app is working correctly, but **AS SOON AS I add `$stateParams`** in the controller I'm get this error:

`angular.js:14791 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateParamsProvider <- $stateParams <- ClienteViniCtrl`

This is from: **app.js**

```
     .when('/clienti/:id_cliente', {
    templateUrl: 'views/cliente-vini.html',
    controller: 'ClienteViniCtrl'
  })
```

This is from: **controller.js**

```
  .controller('ClienteViniCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Vini){
  Vini.getWines($stateParams.id_cliente).then(function (result) {
      $scope.vini = result;
  })
```

What's the problem?

Comment: add $state before $stateParams

Comment: They are used with `ui.router` not `ngRoute`, change to `$routeParams`

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem! @AlekseySolovey

Answer (score 0):

Do you have added angular-ui-router.js at your project?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```

Comment: his config has `.when(` not `.state(`, so it's `ngRoute`